# Differences between std::endl and '\n' for streambuffer implementations

Tags: c++, stringbuffer, endl

I'm currently trying to implement a subclass of stringbuf to allow the buffer to tokenize for specific chars ('\n' in my case) and undertake an action if this char occurs (dump the message to a logger and clear buffer afterwards in my case). 
To achieve this goal, I overrode sputc (to implement watching out for the '\n') and xsputn (to use sputc indeed, as the GCC implementation doesn't seem to do this by default). 
For debugging purposes, I let sputc write out each character that is passed to it to stdout.

Now this is my question: If I use something like

```
mystream << "Some text" << std::endl;
```

sputc receives each character except of the '\n' which should be inducted by std::endl, so the action that is expected is not done because the '\n' isn't passed on.
If I use something like

```
mystream << "Some text" << '\n';
```

or even

```
mystream << "Some text" << "\n" << std::flush;
```

everything works as expected and my sputc implementation gets the '\n' char.

So my question is: Shouldn't both code lines do exactly the same concerning the stringbuf behind, and if not, which other methods do I have to override to get the '\n'?

Comment: `<< std::endl` does, precisely, `<< '\n' << std::flush;`.

Comment: There are easier ways to do what you are trying to do. Maybe if you ask a question about the real problem you can get advice about the best way to solve it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't override `sputc` because `sputc` is not virtual. You need to overload `overflow` and `sync` and examine the whole pending sequence for occurrences of `\n`.

You shouldn't really need to overload `xsputn` unless you can do something optimal because you know something special about the device that backs your stream type.

Comment: I found that out yesterday myself and overloaded overflow as you say, and now everything works.